# How to count the number of arguments passed under condition?

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting, function

I'm trying to create a shell script taking as argument a series of averages and assign for each note an observation, example :

There are 5 averages that are introduced.
There are 2 notes that are: pretty good.
There are 3 notes that are: well
....

```
for i in $@
if [[ $# -ge 16 ]]; 
then 
    let j++
    echo " there are ${#j} notes that are : pretty good "
elif [[ $# -ge 14 ]]; 
    let k++
    echo " there are ${#k} notes that are : good "
```

Answer (score 1):

Count your things first, then separately report the result:

```
#!/bin/bash

for a do
    if (( a >= 10 && a < 12 )); then
        pass=$(( pass + 1 ))
    elif (( etc. for the other conditions ))
    fi
done

printf '%d passed (%d%%)\n' "$pass" "$(( (100*pass)/$# ))"
```

There is no need to test on `$#` as the loop (if written as above) would not execute at all if no arguments were passed.